# How to validate a date input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datatables

I am using the Datatables-Editor JQuery plug-in to build a table. Two of the table's fields are date fields, one for the start-date and one for the end-date. So, when the user creates a new entry I need to validate that the end-date the user sets is after the start-date.

To do that I followed the example that was given as an answer to a similar question here, but I am not sure how to adjust it to work with editor. The code is:

```
        $('date', editor.field('manage.from_date').node()).datepicker({
            onSelect: function(selected) {
                $('date', editor.field('manage.to_date').node()).datepicker("option","minDate", selected);
            }
        });

         $('date', editor.field('manage.to_date').node()).datepicker({
            onSelect: function(selected) {
                $('date', editor.field('manage.from_date').node()).datepicker("option","maxDate", selected);
            }
        });
```

And the initialization of the table is here:

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    "ajax": "php/table.manage.php",
    "table": "#manage",
    "fields": [
          ...
        {
            "label": "From Date",
            "name": "manage.from_date",
            "type": "date",
            "dateFormat": "D, d M yy",
            "dateImage": "images\/calender.png"
        },{
            "label": "To Date",
            "name": "manage.to_date",
            "type": "date",
            "dateFormat": "D, d M yy",
            "dateImage": "images\/calender.png"
        }
        ...
```

So, I can't figure out how to access, through JQuery, the date fields in order to make the necessary changes.

Any help would be really useful, thanks!!

Comment: field or fields?  - I ask because both of your code samples have different references.

Comment: @jamesemanon what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Time, dates, timezones and localization is really tricky. Without knowing requirements, I recommend [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to do the heavy lifting.